# How do I import fernet?

Tags: python, cryptography

I am relatively new to python and am following this tutorial on encrypting strings and files in python: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H8t4DJ3Tdrg

I have downloaded pip, but when I try to generate a key, using this code:

```
from cryptography.fernet import fernet

key - Fernet.generate_key()
print (key)
```

I get the following error in terminal:

```
File "randomkey.py", line 1, in <module>
    from cryptography.fernet import fernet
ImportError: cannot import name fernet
```

How do I fix this? Thanks

Comment: have you done `pip install cryptography`?

Answer (score 2):

There is a typo.

The class name is `Fernet` with capital `F`.

```
from cryptography.fernet import Fernet
```